# How to change monaco editor background colour in React

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor

I'm looking to change the background colour of the monaco editor. Im using the following monaco npm package with React: [Monaco React](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@monaco-editor/react)

Is there a way to do this in the Editor component below? The options object I have below works perfectly so hoping to do something similar with the editor background colour.

Should I be using the [defineTheme function](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.editor.html#definetheme) for this?

Here's the editor code I'm trying to get working:

```
<Editor
        height="90vh"
        width="870px"
        language="javascript"
        line="2"
        options={{
          minimap: {
            enabled: false,
          },
          fontSize: 18,
          cursorStyle: "block",
          wordWrap: "on",
        }}
        defineTheme={{
          themeName: "my-theme",
          themeData: {
            colors: {
              "editor.background": "#000000",
            },
          },
        }}
        value={"// write your code here"}
        editorDidMount={handleEditorDidMount}
      />
```

Comment: According to [props docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@monaco-editor/react#props) it looks like `theme` takes only an enum string of `light|dark`.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 steps to achieve your goal

1. Define your custom theme with custom colors
2. Notify Monaco to use that theme

working example

https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#customizing-the-appearence-exposed-colors

If you want to do it in React,
In ComponentDidMount (classComponent) or in useEffect(functionalComponent), define your custom theme using monaco editor's [define theme](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.editor.html#definetheme) interface.

```
monaco.editor.defineTheme('my-theme', {
      base: 'vs',
      inherit: true,
      rules: [],
      colors: {
        'editor.background': '#000000',
      },
});
```

and then while rendering Editor component pass 'my-theme' as theme prop to Editor component.

```
<Editor
   height="90vh"
   width="870px"
   language="javascript"
   theme="my-theme"
   line="2"
   options={{
     minimap: {
       enabled: false,
     },
     fontSize: 18,
     cursorStyle: "block",
     wordWrap: "on",
   }}
   value={"// write your code here"}
   editorDidMount={handleEditorDidMount}
/>
```

In the npm repository you are using, there is one predefined additional theme available. (`night-dark`).
Which is defined as follows

```
{
    base: 'vs-dark',
    inherit: true,
    rules: [],
    colors: {
      'editor.background': '#202124',
    },
},
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the docs aren't very clear about this, but you can't simply add your custom theme in the `<Editor />` component itself, after you've defined it.
You need to call two different functions from the Monaco instance.
The first is `monaco.editor.defineTheme()`, in `handleEditorDidMount`. The second is `monaco.editor.setTheme()` in `handleEditorDidMount`.

It seems like because of the order of the phases, `handleEditorDidMount` will be called after the Editor component has been rendered with the other props, and after the `theme` has been set if it has been defined as a prop.
So to add your custom theme, you can leave out the `theme` prop, and instead add `defineTheme('myTheme', {})` and `setTheme('myTheme')` in `handleEditorDidMount`